How to typehint an intermediate value in chained code using PHPDoc
I have the following code:
$id = $ui->getWidget('import_id')->value;

I know the class type of $ui.  The getWidget() method can return one or more types of widget classes based on the parameter passed in.  Some of those widget classes have a value parameter, and some don't.
If I want to add a doc hint to say "I know what this particular value of getWidget() is returning", can I do that without splitting up my code?  i.e. I know I can accomplish this by adding an intermediate variable, e.g.:
/** @var KnownClassWithValueProperty $idClass */
$idClass = $ui->getWidget('import_id');
$id = $idClass->value;

But ideally I'd like to not do this, but somehow type-hint the value of $ui->getWidget('import_id').
Thanks!

To the best of my knowledge you can't type hint method chains like that without using the intermediate variable as you showed. This post from four years ago confirms that, and I couldn't find any updated guidance. One other option, which you probably don't want to do, either, is add a dedicated method to the class that $ui based on, with a getWidgetForBlahBlah(), and set the return value for that. Obviously this doesn't scale well, but you do get the added benefit of runtime type enforcement by PHP at least.

Thanks @ChrisHaas ... that's kinda what I expected.  Oh well!
